# PowersShell script doesn't work remotely with Invoke-Command but works perfectly locally

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, windows-update

I have a script to check for and download windows updates. It isn't working remotely and I would like to know why. Here is the script:

```
    $UpdateSession = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session
    $updatesToDownload = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
    $updatesToInstall = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
    $UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
    $Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    # Check for updates ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($SearchResult.Updates.Count -gt 0)    {
        Write-Host("All updates found: " + $SearchResult.Updates.Count)
        For ($X = 0; $X -lt $SearchResult.Updates.Count; $X++)    {
            $Update = $SearchResult.Updates.Item($X)
            if ($Update.KBArticleIDs -eq '2267602')    {
                Write-Host("Updates with Ids 2267602 found: " + $Update.Title)
                $updatesToDownload.Add($Update)
                Write-Host("Update " + $Update.Title + " added to download list")
            }
        }
    }
    else    {
        # Write-Host(0) # No Security Intelligence Updates
        Write-Host("No update found")
        Exit
    }
    # Download updates ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($updatesToDownload.Count -gt 0)    {
        Write-Host("Start download process")
        $Downloader.Updates = $updatesToDownload
        $DownloadResult = $Downloader.Download()
        Write-Host("Download ResultCode: " + $DownloadResult.ResultCode)
        if ($DownloadResult.ResultCode -eq 2)    {
            For ($X = 0; $X -lt $updatesToDownload.Count; $X++)    {
                Write-Host("Adding updates to install list")
                $Update = $updatesToDownload.Item($X)
                if ($update.IsDownloaded -eq 'True')    {
                    $updatesToInstall.Add($Update)
                    Write-Host("Update " + $Update.Title + " added to install list")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else    {
        # Write-Host(0) # No Security Intelligence Updates
        Write-Host("No update to download found")
        Exit
    }
```

The script works perfectly when I run it on a computer using administrator account.
But when I try to run it remotely using below short script and the same administrator credentials it starts and do "Check for updates" bloc and stops with error.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "some_password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("computer_name\administrator", $password)
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName "computer_name" -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -FilePath "D:\Test.ps1"
```

Where `"D:\Test.ps1"` is path to a file with script mentioned above.

Error message:

```
The property 'Updates' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : computer_name
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : computer_name
```

I have checked remote credentials using other script (below) and the result is True yet updates script doesn't work.

```
[bool] (net session 2>$null)
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
```

What did I do wrong? Why doesn't the script work remotely?

Comment: I’d take a look at the event log but I’ve never been able to manually install windows updates remotely. It’s natively blocked by Microsoft afaik

Comment: The error messages are related to   ```$Downloader.Updates = $updatesToDownload;        $DownloadResult = $Downloader.Download()```, indicating that this ```$UpdateSession = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session``` did not work.  There are some workarounds, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078958/powershell-remote-microsoft-update-session-access-denied-0x80070005

Comment: I think there's a rights issue where you have to use task scheduler instead.